# Nested template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I've started reading about templates, and I found that smart pointers use double templates, something like this:

```
template <class T>
class myclass
{
public:
   template <class U>
   myclass(U* q) { /* ... */ }
};
```

What is the meaning of that? I know templated functions will deduce `U`, as

```
myclass(new whatever(3));
```

where `U` will be `whatever*`. So what is `T`? What is the relationship between `U` and `T`?

I'm confused...

Comment: The word is not "double", it's "nested". You cannot call it like that, you need `myclass<something>(new whatever(3));`. That is you need to provide both T and U somehow.

Comment: Actually you would need `myclass<base>(new whatever(3));`. Class template arguments cannot be deduced. What is relation between `T` and `U` depends on your code and I doesn't follow strictly from such simple example. I think it might require `T` to be base class of `U`, but it depends on what the whole class is about.

Comment: That must not be the whole class. `T` is somewhere else.

Comment: Note that in your example, `U` is **not** `whatever*` but `whatever`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above sample code imposes no relationship between `T` and `U`.

One is the type argument passed to the class template `myclass`, the other is a deduced type passed to the constructor.

However, where you found it (in `std::shared_ptr` probably) it gets more interesting.

Now, in `std::shared_ptr`, the body of the constructor imposes a requirement that `U` be a descendent type from `T`.  That constructor allows you to create a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` from a `Derived*` while knowing within the constructor that it is being constructed from a `Derived*`.

Why would we want this?  After all, a `Derived*` can be converted to a `Base*` outside the constructor, so why not just take a `T*` (aka `Base*`)?

Well, a `std::shared_ptr<T>` is 3 things bundled together.  It is a `T*`, a reference counter, and a cleanup function (a "Deleter").

When the reference count is reduced to 0, the cleanup function is called.  By default, the cleanup function calls the destructor of the pointed to object.

But which destructor?  Well, the destructor called is based off of the type `U`, **not** `T`.  At construction, a destruction function is written that knows the static type `U`.  This destruction function is carried around to all copies of that original `shared_ptr<T>`, so even if it is destroyed far away it still invokes `~U` instead of `~T`.

If `T` has a `virtual ~T()` this doesn't do much (and in fact, identical comdat folding or similar techniques will make it do nothing), but if it has a non-virtual destructor, `shared_ptr` will call the proper destructor (assuming the type is actually `U` and not some derived type of `U`).

`shared_ptr` needs to store the destruction function for other reasons (you can pass in custom destruction functions), so this doesn't have significant overhead.

Comment: Holy moly, that's brilliant! Thanks Yakk, I think I now understand. Now just to clarify, wouldn't it work using simply `T*` for the costructor? For instance `class A`, and `class B : public A`, a shared pointer with just `T*` wouldn't work when used in `shared_ptr<A>(new B);`?

Comment: @user75700 With a `T*`, the constructor doesn't know the pointer is a `U`.  So when it creates the destroyer, it can only call `~T` not `~U`.  By taking a `U*`, it knows the pointer "really" is a `U`, so the destruction function it stores can call `~U`.  As noted, this mostly only matters when `T` has a non-`virtual` destructor (if `~U` was `final` it would also enable optimizations).

Comment: @Yakk Out of curiosity: Did you find this out by a) reading the standard, b) peeking into the `memory` header, or c) trying / experimenting. Great answer BTW!

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I don't think I've read the `memory` header in any detail: those headers are all but unreadable in my experience.  I've implemented my own `shared_ptr` type classes.  So probably a bit of (a) and (c) and some hanging out here.  If you look at the cppreference docs for the `shared_ptr` constructor things are also made a bit clearer than the standard directly.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `myclass` is a *template class* and the constructor `myclass::myclass()` is a *template method*. Both must be given a type so that they can "work" properly, where "given" may also mean that the type is deduced.

For example a valid declaration of an instance of `myclass` is

```
myclass<double> x(new int(3));
```

Here `T = double` and `U = int` (note that the constructor takes a `U*`). There doesn't need to be a relationship between `U` and `T`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between `T` and `U`. You can instantiate `myclass` with any `T` and call a constructor with any argument as long as it's a pointer (in your case):

```
class A {};
class B {};
myClass<A> x(new B()); // T == A, U == B
```

Note that you can't explicitly specify `U`, it can only be deduced from the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a class template:

```
template<typename T>
class Element
{
    T _element;
public:
    CopyFrom(T t);
};
```

What if you want to `CopyFrom` any type that is *not* `T`. For example:

```
Element<int> a;
a.CopyFrom(10.0f);
```

Here, just for understanding `int` to `float` conversion is not possible, and only `CopyFrom` can do it (using some helper functions, some other internal overload function etc.) - But to avoid any *Loss of data* warning. Therefore, you want something like:

```
a.CopyFrom<float>(10.0f);
```

Here, you specified the argument type as `float` - compiler will now be happy. To make it work, you'd make `CopyFrom` a function (method) template:

```
public:
        template<typename U>
        CopyFrom(U t);
```

Now, `a` is of type `Element<int>`, but `CopyFrom` would be `CopyFrom<float>`. Obviosuly, you need not to use `<float>`.

```
a.CopyFrom/*<float>*/(10.0f); // Element<int>::CopyFrom<float>(...);
```